vertical line disappear
During last half year sometimes vertical line disappears from my pdf file. when it disappeared from frame, I do not care. But when I draw diagram, it is very important to show all arrows. In following example middle arow disappeared
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix
{
V_1\ar[r]^{f_1}&V_2\ar[r]^{f_2}&...\ar[r]^{f_{n-1}}&V_n\\
D_1\ar[r]^{f_1}\ar[u]|-{*}&D_2\ar[r]^{g_2}\ar[u]|-{*}&...\ar[r]^{g_{n-1}}&D_n\ar[u]|-{*}
}
\]

\end{document}



Where do you use framed in your code?

I see no “disappearing” arrow. All those that are specified do appear.

It appears that this is problem of preview by TexWorks. Not the problem of compilation. When I change scale, one or other vertical line appears or disappears. Ultimately, on some scale I saw image as I expected. Thank you for support.

I am happy that you have found the solution. Alleluia :-)))
